# Is it dangerous when I returning the entity after SaveChangesAsync?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, repository-pattern, savechanges

I want to know what is wrong in this code? Can it cause some errors in multiple requests at the same time and calling this method in the controller web api?

```
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: You are already passing entity so you have object reference, I don't think you need to return it when object reference is unchanged.

Comment: `public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)` - this looks like the Repository Pattern. If you are using Entity Framework then you **should not use the Repository (Anti-) Pattern**! See here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/220126

Comment: Is `_dbContext` a static field that has a long lifespan or is it a short-lived object that won't last longer than the associated incoming HTTP request?

Comment: If I have similar code for delete, what is wrong in this code?   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
             await someRepo.AddAsync(params);

            await _cartService.DeleteAsync(params.Id);

            return View("Index", model);
        }

Comment: Yes I have implemented repository pattern

Comment: This is not a good question for stackoverflow, However i second the "*dont use repository over EF sentiment*", in my opinionated opinion, that is the only thing wrong with the code atm. also you are caching your DbContext for who knows how long

Comment: Why cashing DbContext is wrong ?

Comment: It isn't wrong if it's only short, however the longer you keep it open the more likely you have connection errors and other oddities

Answer (score 1):

Objects (custom or not) are by definition referenced. Which inherently means that any changes made throughout methods are reflected to your base object.

In short, returning the same object you are already passing in the parameters is unnecessary. When you insert the object into the table, the ID will get assigned to it (if applicable) and this will be updated through all your classes as long as the reference of the object stays the same.